# Warn user when new data is inserted on database

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I don't know how to search about this so I'm kinda lost (the two topics I saw here were closed).

I have a news website and I want to warn the user when a new data is inserted on the database. I want to do that like here on StackOverflow where we are warned without reloading the page or like in facebook where you are warned about new messages/notifications without reloading.

Which is the best way to do that? Is it some kind of listener with a timeout that is constantly checking the database? It doesn't sounds efficient...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need javascript ajax and json and callback function to check constantly. It can be done by push services but PHP is bad with that and you need websockest, etc. facebook uses timeout calls. not sure for the stackoverflow

```
   refreshInterval = 500
  refreshTimeout = setTimeout( getNotificationCounts, refreshInterval );
function getNotifications() {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'path_to_your_php',
            type : 'POST',
                    data:   //put for exampel user_id but it cvan be handled by sesion as well
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function(data) {
                alert('You have'+ data.total +' new messages')
                refreshTimeout = setTimeout( getNotificationCounts, refreshInterval ); //this will check every half of second
            }
        });
    }
```

then in PHP, for example you have a flag in database with which  you check if data is new to teh databse. Mind the formatting and to proper sql escape

```
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as total from myTable where user_id=$_POST['user_id'] AND is_read=0"); 

      //note instad of $_POST you can use session if users are logged in, or however you are handling it
        $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        echo json_encode($data)
```

;

After that you can create another ajax call that marks messages as read once user clicks on them. or opens a dialog listing or wahtever

```
mysql_query("UPDATE myTable WHERE user_id=$_POST['user_id'] SET  is_read=1");
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply Elijan. I have thought about this timeout solution. I didn't know facebook uses that. It seems so unefficient for a system with thousands of user threads (lot of database access). I wonder if there is a way to trigger an event (like a notify()) all over the current user threads when data is inserted, but for now the timeout solution will fit the problem, thanks.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin  Well if you structure database correctly (in latest user app I built we have notification table, which basically deals with all the stuff) and indexed it it is nor much of an overhead (you don't query user threads, but when user thread is created you add an entry to notification table) . Problem to push notification the way you want is that client at that point needs to becomes a server  , facebook used to ping the server consonantly every x n of seconds . Now i think they have a  "pull listener" which is an ajax request that waits for new data. see via firebug.

Comment: @JoãoMenighin Also google "push notfications fro PHp" for more details on how it can be done without ajax requests (as said it requires web seockets and node.js  so you still have to have fallbacks)